# How to paste the code in question block?

Tags: discussion, android

Is there any reason why I can't paste my code into the question block? As per the comment below I tried indenting it all 4 spaces and all of it 8 spaces; it just doesn't work what is the trick too it ?

Comment: Use the code sample button in the toolbar.

Comment: That's still not working is there any other reason

Comment: check your code and keep the 4 space in every line of code..

Comment: Something wrong in your pasting.  It does work.

Comment: Yeh thought so lol thanks for all your help Ill try meta.stackflow.com

Answer (score -1):

paste your code like this hope it's worked now:

[image]